# Is it possible for the adapter to send two items at a time to the dropdownlistview in android

Tags: android, json, adapter

When i click on a item in dropdownlistview of android i want it to display the id of the respective item.

json data:

```
{"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Beverages"},{"id":"2","name":"Bread"},{"id":"3","name":"Cereals"},{"id":"4","name":"Cheese"},{"id":"5","name":"Citrus Fruits"}]}
```

Comment: Two items means two different category name or anything else? Just clarify your question. And I am able to understand your question then yes it will be.

Comment: When i click on a item in dropdownlistview of android i want it to display the id of the respective item.

Comment: Yes you can do it. Are you using ListView? If yes then you can use onItemClick method of it

Comment: Actually i am using spinner not listview,how about this?

Comment: You can use OnItemSelectedListener method for Spinner. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151414/how-can-i-use-onitemselected-in-android