# OnItemClickListener() for spinners in each item of a list view

Tags: android, listview, listener, spinner, custom-adapter

I have a list view with its own custom adapter and I have put a spinner in every item of that list view but the problem is, the items are added by the user so i don't know how to catch it when he makes a selection in the spinners.

PS. i have put a spinner in every item of that list view but i don't know how to listen for selections in those inner spinners.

So do i put the onIitemClickListener inside the GetView() of the custom adapter or in the MainActivity()'s onCreate function?

The spinner does have an id but since i'm using a custom list view, each spinner is almost as if all have the same id unless i specify the item of the list view inside the GetView() but even then is it possible to put a listener inside getView() and have it running 24/7?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using for the spinners?

Comment: what do u mean, spinners don't have code i put them in the .xml using design and i just called their id from the getView()

Comment: @Appafly which code where do i find it

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the OnItemClickListener inside the OnCreate() method using GetView(). You don't nessecarily need an id as long as you are using GetView() correctly. There is also an OnItemSelectedListener that you can use if you want to. You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151414/how-can-i-use-onitemselected-in-android).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't get how i can insert code into onCreate() using getView()

Answer (score 1):

First I advice you to use Recyclerview, you can take item selected from spinner with this

```
public class TestSpinnerInListView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestSpinnerInListView.TestSpinnerHolder> {


@NonNull
@Override
public TestSpinnerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TestSpinnerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_test,parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TestSpinnerHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.spTest.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Do something
            holder.tvTest.setText((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 3;
}

class TestSpinnerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView tvTest;
    public Spinner spTest;
    public TestSpinnerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTest = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        spTest = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sptest);

    }
}
```

}