# I Want To Itemonclicklister in Fragment on Spinner

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner

This Is Main Fragment
Fragment:

```
  private void getStock() {
          dialog.show();
          Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance();
          apiInterface api = retrofit.create(apiInterface.class);
          Call<List<Blocks>>call = api.getVaccineBlocks();
          call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Blocks>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<Blocks>>call, Response<List<Blocks>> response) {
                  if (response.code() == 200) {
                      block = response.body();
                     spinnerada();
                      dialog.cancel();
  
                  }else{
                      dialog.cancel();
  
                  }
              }
  
              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<Blocks>> call, Throwable t) {
                  dialog.cancel();
              }
          });
      }
  
      private void spinnerada() {
  
  
          String[] s = new String[block.size()];
          for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
              s[i] = block.get(i).getBlockName();
              final ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
              a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
              //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
              spinner.setAdapter(a);
            
          }
  
  
      }
```

This Is Blocks Model
model:

```
    package com.smmtn.book.models;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    
    public class Blocks implements Serializable {
        public String id;
        public String blockName;
        public String blockSlug;
    
    
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getBlockName() {
            return blockName;
        }
    
        public void setBlockName(String blockName) {
            this.blockName = blockName;
        }
    
        public String getBlockSlug() {
            return blockSlug;
        }
    
        public void setBlockSlug(String blockSlug) {
            this.blockSlug = blockSlug;
        }
    }
```

here i need onitemclick  with blockslug please any one can help, am new to android so i need some example.when on click i want take blockslug and load another method with that blockslug,like will get data from u "http://example.com/block/"+blockslug
i want to get blockslug from selected block
i hope guys i will get help
and sorry for my bad English,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to implement `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151596/9346054

Once you selected the item, you can call them by making a new method. Example like below

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final String itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    showBlockSlug(itemSelected);
}
```

And then, at the method `showBlockSlug()` , you can call Retrofit.

```
private void showBlockSlug(final String blockslug){
   final String url = "http://example.com/block/"+ blockslug;
   //Do your stuff...
}
```